# How to count objects in array?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

So I've been working with symfony for a while and I'm trying to understand how it works. So, I tried to count how many tasks do I have in my *tasks* array.

This is my homeController.php class:

```
 public function succesfulLogin(Request $request)
{

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Task');
    $tasks = $repository->findByAuthor($this->getUser()->getUsername());
    $points = 0;

    foreach($tasks as $task){
        $points++;
    }

    return $this->render(
        'userpage.html.twig',array('username' => $username = $this->getUser()->getUsername(), 'tasks' => $tasks, 'points' => $points ));
    $user->getTasks();
   //as I understant I return '$tasks' array to twig with all my tasks
   //so before returning '$tasks' array it should have 21 object in it?(not 13)
   //am I wrong?
}
```

So I pass 'points' to twig and twig prints out number **13**, but when I try to print out all *tasks* in twig, it says that I have 21 task.
There is some twig code:

```
{% for task in tasks %}//this foreach loop prints out 21 task
        <tr>
            <td id>{{ task.Id }}</td>
            <td>{{ task.Status }}</td>
            <td>{{ task.Name }}</td>
            <td>{{ task.Description }}</td>
            <td>{{ task.Category }}</td>
            <td>{{ task.Author }}</td>
            <td>{{ task.CreationDate|date("m/d/Y") }}</td>
            <td><a id="myLink" href="/edit/{{ task.ID }}" > Edit </a></td>
            <td><a id="myLink" href="/delete/{{ task.ID }}" >Delete</a></td>
            <?php echo 2+2; ?>            </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Check which SQL is generated by `$repository->findByAuthor($this->getUser()->getUsername())` and which SQL is generated by `$user->getTasks()` and try to run these raw SQL queries againt your database.

Comment: Use `dump($tasks);` in the controller to check what is inside.

Comment: @COil where should I get the answer? In my web?

Comment: @Matěj Račinský Thank you, I'll try.

Comment: Yes, add a die(); to see in your browser, if there is no die, you will see the result in the debug bar.

Comment: php inside of a twig template is not going to work well.  In any event, twig has support for counting the number of elements in an array.  {{ $tasks | length }} Lots of other helper functions as well. https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/length.html

Comment: @Coil wow thanks! Know I know what's wrong :) Problem fixed, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you should use `count()` or `sizeof()` function in PHP for getting count of the objects. So you could just run `$points = count($tasks)` instead of iterations over `$tasks` and incrementing.

If you'd like to get array count in twig template, you could use built-in `length` filter.

```
{% set tasks_count = tasks|length %}
```